# How to store the data into developer icloud account

Tags: ios, iphone, icloud

I am doing one application.In that i want to store the data permanently in my iCloud account.If i use the icloud feature in my app,data is store into users iCloud account or developer icloud account.

Comment: You want to release an app where the data saved by every user of the app is stored in _your_ iCloud account? I don't think that's possible (or wise)

Comment: Then data is stored in owner of device account?

Comment: Yes it is. A device can only access one iCloud account at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With iCloud, apps can only access the user's iCloud account. The app can access whatever account the user has configured on their device, and there's no API for accessing any other account. The entire system is designed as a way for people to sync their data across multiple devices, so there's no option to share data or access other accounts in any way.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but if you're looking for some kind of server-side component for your app, there are lots of options. [Parse](https://parse.com) is very popular, as is [Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/), but there are many other services. If you're not prepared to set up your own server, you can integrate one of them. But your app will only access *your* iCloud account when it runs on *your* device.